# LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I am new in spring security I have been done everything in tutorial, but i got this exception.

I have a simple Spring Security + JSF web app:

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <!--JSF -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`security-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="sajjad" password="414141" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

The `spring-config.xml` is empty.

Here is my dependencies:

```
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i get this exception when i run the application:

```
25-May-2015 02:35:11.113 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
25-May-2015 02:35:11.114 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
25-May-2015 02:35:11.125 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon May 25 02:35:09 GMT+03:30 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
...

5-May-2015 02:35:11.127 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon May 25 02:35:09 GMT+03:30 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree` and make sure you aren't mixing different versions of spring jars.

Comment: Alt + F5 and refresh project after it.

Comment: @M.Deinum should i remove old versions of dependencies from repository folder? For example i have three version of spring in that folder, but i use the last version in project.

Comment: Please post output not screenshots. You executed it from some random directory, you must execute `mvn dependency:tree` from your projects directory.

Comment: @M.Deinum In root path of application?

Comment: No the directory containing the pom.

Comment: @M.Deinum See picture again, i do that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry for small image, please zoom in it.

Comment: i doubt that, judging from the error and I doubt that your users home directory is the directory containing your projects pom. That is also what the error quite clearly tells you, that there is no pom.xml file.

Comment: @M.Deinum The `pom.xml` is in `securoty3` directory, see the second image.

Comment: Then execute the command from that directory... Understand the tools you are using is key to solve your problems...

Comment: @M.Deinum The first picture is the result of the `mvn dependency:tree` statement in the `/Desktop/security3` directory.

Comment: please don't post images, post text as images are unreadable...

Comment: Your versions look ok, enable debug logging to see what is happening during startup.

Comment: @M.Deinum You mean start application in debug mode?

Comment: No... I mean enable debug logging for `org.springframework`.

Comment: @M.Deinum How do that?

Answer (score 11):

Encountered the same problem. It was caused by using java 8 in combination with some spring dependencies. Haven't figured it out which, but using java 7 solved the problem at the time.

Answer (score 5):

Deploy right version of spring and its dependencies with right version of tomcat, 
for eg - Spring 3.2 with Jersey 2.22 in Tomcat 8 and not in tomcat 7.
Spring 3.0 with Jersey 2 in tomcat 7
See the version compatibility

Answer (score 5):

You can have this error if you use Spring and you add an External Jar manually in the project properties instead of using the dedicated dependency file "pom.xml".

Answer (score 1):

For me it was caused by a dependency which introduced an incompatible dependency. I had to exclude the unnecessary root dependencies:

```
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Otherwise, Webapp doesn't start up -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using older version of Tomcat for my project and I was getting same error. I updated it to Tomcat 9 and its working fine now. You should update version as per compatibility of those systems with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Removing and re adding the project in the server helped me to solve the issue

Comment: such advice suits in comment not in answer

Comment: @Gahan, less reputation caused me to put it in answer

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this exception recently. For me it was happening when trying to deploy a spring pod in a kubernetes cluster, the pod was being killed before spring had a chance to boot up properly and start responding to the health check.

The fix for me was just to increase the delay before checking the healthcheck endpoint.

It may be worth checking if something is killing spring during startup if you're seeing this error

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exception and in my case the solution was fixing a typo in a @Repository("the typo was here") tag in one of mine DAO implementations